# Assume list type is int java

Tags: java, arrays, list, types, casting

I have a function that returns a list of values. I want to use the values in that list as parameters in another function.

```
private static List test(){
    List myList;
    mylist.add(1);
    return myList;
};
```

Now here's the catch. When I say

```
lst = test();
myFunction(lst.get(1));
```

`lst.get(1)` is type object. But `myFunction` requires an int. I've tried casting it into lots of things. When I say `(int) lst.get(1);` my compiler returns this error:

```
C:\Users\...\workspace\...\....txt
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
    at ///.///.Encode(///.java:73)
    at ///.///.main(///.java:25)
```

When I just have it with no cast, I get this red underline and error:

```
The method ENCODEScrambleNum(int, int, int, int, String) in the type kriptik is not applicable for the arguments (Object, Object, Object, Object, String)
```

Method signature:

```
ENCODEScrambleNum(int, int, int, int, String)
```

Calling it:

```
ENCODEScrambleNum(key.get(0), key.get(1), key.get(2), key.get(3), str);
```

Is there a way that I can tell the computer before hand that the list type will be an int?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with R.J, if you specify the type of list as integer and use get() function, it will always return an integer. I tried below code, hope it helps :

```
private static List<Integer> test(){

List<Integer> myList = new ArrayList<Integer>(); 
for(int i=0; i<4; i++){ myList.add(i+10);} //included a for loop just to put something in the list
return myList;
}

private static String ENCODEScrambleNum(Integer get, Integer get0, Integer get1, Integer get2, String in_here) {
     return "I am " + in_here + " with list items-" + get + get0 + get1 + get2; //Dummy logic
}
```

Comment: It is still acting like `key.get(1);` is an object. It will not recognize it as an Integer.

Answer (score 2):

Oh yes, you can do that. Just by declaring the type of the list like this

```
private static List<Integer> test(){
    //List<Integer> myList; // list is not initialized yet(NPE is waiting for you)
    List<Integer> myList = new ArrayList<Integer>(); // List initialized
    mylist.add(1);
    return myList;
} // Why was a semi-colon here?
```

When you try to send `list.get(1)` as an `int` parameter, it'll be autoboxed. So you need not worry about that.

Comment: Hmm... Still getting the same compile error. Still acting like they are objects.

Comment: Can you post the signature of your `myFunction()` method and how exactly are you trying to call it with the `list` entries as parameters?

Comment: String numText = ENCODEScrambleNum(key.get(1), key.get(2), key.get(3), key.get(4));

Comment: That is assuming that key = test()

Comment: Please edit your question and post the method signature, along with the call there. Posting code here will make the comments quite clumsy.

Comment: Tried your suggestions, and the suggestion of Woody. Same error.

Comment: Solved it. My `key` variable was not defined with `<Integer>` like so: `List<Integer> key = test();`. So... It looks like none of you really solved it... But I'll give it to @rohit because he only has 12 reputation and he put forward equal effort.

Answer (score 2):

```
private static List test(){
    List myList;
    mylist.add(1);    //Here the value 1 is added at zeroth index.
    return myList;
}
```

Replace your code as

```
lst = test();
myFunction(lst.get(0));  //Retrieves the value at zeroth index.
```

instead of,

```
lst = test();
myFunction(lst.get(1)); //Retrieves the value at first index
```

because the `List` index starts from `0` and not from `1`.

Comment: Tried that, didn't help. Thanks, though.